# How to use Facebook Graph api

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph Api for my application where i want the data of this page.

http://www.facebook.com/pages/

In this page there is option [TV SHOW](http://www.facebook.com/pages/#!/pages/?browse&ps=89) I want collect all information of that page.
But i didn't any graph api method for this page.

Please help me for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this isn't something you can do. It has to do with what Facebook sets as "indexable" columns in their tables. For example, the `page` table has a `type` ID and the TV SHOWS category ID appears to be 89, so you'd think you could run a FQL query such as:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT page_id, name FROM page WHERE type=89
```

or perhaps:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT page_id, name FROM page WHERE type='TV SHOW'
```

But you'll get this notice:

> Your statement is not indexable. The
>   WHERE clause must contain an indexable
>   column.

Unfortunately, the only two indexable columns for WHERE statements using the `page` table are `page_id` and `name`. So you can only query this table for one page at a time. Which makes sense when you consider how expensive a search like that would be on billions of records.

You can do a generic graph search for "TV SHOWS" but it won't give the the results on the page index as you requested:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=TV%20SHOWS&type=page
```

The Graph API is more about introspection/connections between objects than an open search protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your ans but it is not what i want. I need this page data. http://www.facebook.com/pages/?browse&ps=89

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that this *is* your answer. It's not possible at this time. You could scrape the page but I wouldn't recommend that.